# SUM the number of duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, count, duplicates

I'm using `SELECT count(ID) FROM table1 GROUP BY ID HAVING count(ID) > 1` in order to get how many duplicate rows i have based on my ID field(not a unique value), where each value is the number of duplicates for every id that has duplicates, how could i change the previous query in order to get the sum of those values?
I've tried things like `SELECT count(SELECT count(ID) FROM table1 GROUP BY ID HAVING count(ID) > 1)` for the last hour without any luck.

**input:**

```
    ID|char
    01|f
    01|q
    01|r
    02|q
    03|c
    03|a
    03|s
    03|s
    04|r
    05|q
    06|f
    06|q
```

**result of my query:**

```
count(ID)
3
4
2
```

(3 because we have 3 rows with id==03,4-->4*id==03 etc.)

**desired output:**

```
X
9
```

(9 coming from 3+4+2)

thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Please edit your question to include some sample input and output.  That will help us answer your question.

Comment: Done, Barmar's answer below does what i'm trying to achieve thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(dupCount)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS dupCount
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY ID
      HAVING dupCount > 1) AS x
```